# VBA ParamArray "conditions" to be used in IF statement

Tags: vba, excel

I want to design a Function or Sub that accepts any number of boolean conditions and add them to an IF statement. The code i imagine goes like this:

```
Function comp (ParamArray list() As Variant)
  If (list(0) = True) And (list(1) = true) ..... (list(last) = true) then
'random code
  End If
End Function
```

where list() would be expresions like:

```
x = y-1,somethingToCompare <> anotherThing, etc...
```

It would be interesting if i could add the "and" as another argument, to be changed to "or" if i wished to.

```
Function comp (VyVal compare as Boolean, ParamArray list() As Variant)

dim comparison as String???

  If compare then 
    comparison = "and"
  else
    comparison = "or"
  end if

  If (list(0) = True) comparison (list(1) = true) ..... (list(last) = true) then

    'random code

  End If
End Function
```

The final idea is to use that function like this:

```
Sub code ()

if comp(True, condition1, condition2, ...) then
'random code'

End Sub
```

Avoid directly looking at that code i wrote lest it burn your eyes.

Is something like this posible or should i get a lollipop?

Maybe i'm looking at this in the wrong way, and there's an easier way of doing something similar or even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python (and some other languages) has useful functions `all()` and `any()` which take as input an array (or some other iterable) of Booleans and returns either True or False depending on whether or not some, all, or none of the passed Booleans are True. You could write VBA versions of these (using `Some()` instead of `Any()` since `Any` happens to be a somewhat obscure keyword in VBA):

```
Function All(ParamArray conditions()) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(conditions) To UBound(conditions)
        If Not conditions(i) Then
            All = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    All = True
End Function

Function Some(ParamArray conditions()) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(conditions) To UBound(conditions)
        If conditions(i) Then
            Some = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    Some = False
End Function
```

You could use these functions directly to conditionally call code.

Arguably it might be more useful to change the above definitions to:

```
Function All(conditions As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(conditions) To UBound(conditions)
        If Not conditions(i) Then
            All = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    All = True
End Function

Function Some(conditions As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(conditions) To UBound(conditions)
        If conditions(i) Then
            Some = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    Some = False
End Function
```

Now you would need to use calls like `Some(Array(c1, c2, c3))` rather than `Some(c1,c2,c3)` if you had a literal list of conditions, but you would have the flexibility to pass in an entire array of conditions. Using this second definition you could write something like the following (which answers your original question):

```
Sub Sometimes(when As String, ParamArray conditions())
    Dim run As Boolean
    Dim cond As Variant

    cond = conditions
    run = IIf(when = "All", All(cond), Some(cond))
    If run Then
        Debug.Print "Running random code"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Not running random code"
    End If        
End Sub
```

Then, for example, `Sometimes "Some",True,True,False` results in `Running random code` being printed.

Answer (score 1):

```
sub pointless(byval IsAnd as boolean, paramarray conditions())
  dim i as long

  for i=lbound(conditions) to ubound(conditions)
    if IsAnd then
      if not conditions(i) then exit sub
    else
      if conditions(i) then exit for
    end if
  next

  'random code
end sub
```

But you should realise that the procedure will receive *results* of the comparisons passed to it, not the comparisons themselves. So there is no point really to have such procedure in the first place, you can just write directly in your code:

```
if x = y-1 and somethingToCompare <> anotherThing then
  'random code
end if
```